# Powershell move computer to OU depending on users primary group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am new to powershell and teaching myself but i am trying to figure out if it is possible to use powershell to check a user primary group and then move the computer they are logged onto to a certain OU.

I am looking at having a txt file for showing what ou to move it to depending on primary group.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to download and install [this](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) free `PSSnap-in` from Quest to check the user `PrimaryGroup` and Move computer/user in `ActiveDirectory`.

For retrieve the computer where a User is actually logged on you can use:

[PsLoggedOn](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897545.aspx)

To read the content of a txt file and assign it to a variable in powershell use:

```
$a = get-content c:\OuList.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for that, i will have a look at that